# Change link styling in dataTables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've found the following CSS class handles highlighting an active row in dataTables.

```
.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.active,
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.active,
.table > thead > tr.active > td,
.table > tbody > tr.active > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > td,
.table > thead > tr.active > th,
.table > tbody > tr.active > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
  background-color: #337ab7;

}
```

Producing a result like this:

[image]

The far left column is a link, and one can see how this interferes with my link styling. Currently links are the default blue, I'd like to change it to white. Is it possible to style my links directly in this class?

Bob Rhodes produced the correct answer resulting in this.

```
.table > tbody > tr.active > td > a {color: white}
```

[image]

Thanks again.

Comment: in standard css you cannot nest rules. but if you need to have specific styling for your a tag according to what is selected, you can do `tr.active a {color: #666;}` for instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't quite see how this interferes with your link styling, because you haven't told us how you want your link to be styled.  So, would you tell us?  But yes, it is possible.  What would you like to do?

Comment: BobRodes, I edited the original prompt to say I would like to style the link as white when highlighted.

Comment: I was reading your original example as the top blue line being the header!  No wonder I was confused.  LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a selector that has greater or equal specificity (equal if you reference your CSS file below datatables.css in your page).  A nice tool that you can use is this [CSS specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

I'm not sure why you want to change your link from blue to white, since it's on a very light background and will be hard to see.  But this will do that:

```
.table > tbody > tr.active > td > a {color: white}
```

Now, one thing that you can *not* do is select a `td` element based on the fact that it contains a link.  There's no way in CSS to select a container based on its contents.  You'd have to add a class to the container and select it that way.

Comment: I want to change the link to white when tr is active because that puts the dark blue background behind. This code is correct. I was adding it into the existing datatables.css which was incorrect. I added it in another css document that is loaded after datatables.css.

Comment: @BillTudor Thanks for explaining.  That makes complete sense now.  By the way, if you want the customary underline on your link, then add `text-decoration: underline;` to your style.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
.table > tbody > tr.active a{color: #fff;}
```

Comment: This won't select active rows only, which I think is what the OP wants.

Comment: To clarify for future readers, the poster edited the code to include `.active`.  It will now select active rows only.